# Can Robotframework support keyword driven testing on a C-Sharp developed GUI

Tags: .net, selenium, acceptance-testing, robotframework

Am new to the whole testing automation approach. how can i write keyword driven tests using the robot framework with a .Net developed GUI. am not really certain about this.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of at least three possible solutions.

You could have your GUI implement an xmlrpc server in a separate thread. You could then use the robot [remote library interface](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.7.1#remote-library-interface) to drive the GUI.

The second option is to use the [autoit](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/) library. The advantage is that you don't have to modify your program. The dowside is, you don't have access to the internal state of the GUI.

A third option is to run robot with ironpython, which gives you access to the whole .NET ecosystem. You can write keywords directly in C# to do whatever you need to do to talk to your app.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried all of the above suggestions, and have found that the RF Remote Library combined with [Sharp Robot Remote Server](http://code.google.com/p/sharprobotremoteserver/) (in C#) is by far the best solution.

Worth mentioning is the [White framework](http://white.codeplex.com), which can be combined with your C# library to give you easier access to the UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [Sikuli](http://blog.mykhailo.com/2011/02/how-to-sikuli-and-robot-framework.html), Sikuli introduces new way of automated testing - test using screenshots and images, without using any internal API of objects under test. This approach (using purely images/screenshots and generating mouse and keyboard events) is more similar to manual testing activities performed by real people which have just monitor, mouse and keyboard.